# Angular component template not showing in asp mvc + angular application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I have started with my first angular app. It's running inside an asp.net MVC application.

When i write `<my-app></my-app>` in index.html, it doesn't show me the template of the component. How can I solve this problem?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

ngmudol :

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Add your NgModule to question

Comment: @BabarBilal i edit question

Comment: @Kianoush Add code where you bootstrap you AppModule, if you have done that. Here is example of basic Angular App boostraping: https://toddmotto.com/bootstrap-angular-2-hello-world

Comment: @ImantsVolkovs What code I should write?

Comment: @Kianoush I will write an answer to your question. It will be easier.

Comment: @ImantsVolkovs thank you man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answers given question.

Minimal structure of Anuglar application consists of:

- app.module.ts - Application module (Application root module);
- app.component.ts - Application root component
- app.routes.ts - Application base routes ([Angular router documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html));
- main.ts - place where AppModule is bootstraped;

---

```
//main.ts
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

//Import the App component (root component)
import { App } from './app/app';

//Also import the app routes
import { APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER } from './app/app.routes';

bootstrap(App, [
  APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER,
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

*Source: example nr 2.*

**Examples**:

1. https://toddmotto.com/bootstrap-angular-2-hello-world
2. https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Comment: it show me error to `'./app/app'` , `'./app/app.routes' `, `bootstrap `,` err` , can not find module

Comment: Look at this plunker example[added to answer examples, 3rd one], it may help

Comment: i have tow day this problem .please guide me to solve this problem

Comment: @Kianoush only way to help you now is to see whole code :D So maybe put it together in jsfiddle or plunker. It is hard to guess where might be a problem. But error says, that it cannot find module. For starters, have you compiled this code?

Answer (score 0):

Adding scripts to the cshtml page fixed this problem for me.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MakeBookingLayout.cshtml";
}

@section Scripts
    {
    <script src="~/clientapp/dist/runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="~/clientapp/dist/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/clientapp/dist/styles.js"></script>
    <script src="~/clientapp/dist/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/clientapp/dist/main.js"></script>
    }

<app-root></app-root>
```